# vim search for epoch time strings, pipe to date -d and return the date into the file

Tags: linux, shell, vim, sed

I have a file with a lot of data in it, one being a last-modified="1231231231"

where 1231231231 is epoch time in milliseconds

```
<Translation 
  author_id="25" 
  id="02f18edd-ef7a-48e2-b614-b5888936017e"
  language="de_DE" 
  last_modified="1325669156960" 
  phase="1" 
  target="[ phase=&quot;1&quot; language=&quot;de_DE&quot; ]"
  translation_text="Funktionen"/>
```

Note the: last_modified="1325669156960"

I can run this:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\{10\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1/g
```

to find all these occurrences and replace them with a "seconds" string:

last_modified="1325669156"

I can then pattern match on those 10 digits, and what I'd like to do is pipe them to the unix data -d command to return a formatted data stamp:

```
:%s/[0-9]\{10\}/&/g
```

In this example, instead of replacing with the same value as I found (I.e, the &),

I'd like to somehow pipe that value to what would be essentially:

```
date -d &
```

and return that as a formatted time stamp in the

```
last_modified="Wed Jan  4 07:13:32 MST 2012"
```

Any ideas on how to do this?  I have to do this about every other week on various files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `strftime()` in vim. Find one proper format string to meet your needs.
I'm using `%c` here:

```
:%s/last_modified="\zs\(\d\{10}\)\d\{3}/\=strftime('%c', str2nr(submatch(1)))/g
```

#### result:

```
<Translation 
  author_id="25" 
  id="02f18edd-ef7a-48e2-b614-b5888936017e"
  language="de_DE" 
  last_modified="2012-1-4 17:25:56" 
  phase="1" 
  target="[ phase=&quot;1&quot; language=&quot;de_DE&quot; ]"
  translation_text="Funktionen"/>
```

Comment: I cannot express how thankful I am for this.  I looked for a long time, this works perfectly.  Thank you SO much!!!

Comment: This is so awesome I made it into a ":Timestamps" alias that just looks for any contiguous digits and assumes it's a timestamp (not allows applicable, but good enough for my cases):
command Timestamps %s/\d\@<!\(\d\{10}\)\d\{3}\d\@!/\=strftime('%c', submatch(1))/g